# How to show $\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_0^{\infty} (1-F_X(x)) \, dx$ for a continuous random variable $X \geq 0$ without assuming $f_X$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

If $X$ is a continuous random variable taking non-negative values only, how do I show that $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_0^{\infty}[1-F_X(x)]dx$$

It's easy to give a proof if we assume the density function $f_X$ exists (use Fubini's Theorem to interchange the integrations). However, I got stuck in the general case. What if $X$ does not have a density function?

Comment: "X has a density function" is usually the *definition* of "X is a **continuous** random variable".

Comment: @NateEldredge: The definition I know only requires that the distribution of $X$ assigns zero measure to all singletons (i.e. the distribution function is continuous (not necessarily absolutely continuous)).

Comment: Yeah, an example of a continuous CDF with no PDF is the Cantor staircase.